# Android using Shared Preference as pin code

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have an `Activity` in which I want to ask for a PIN code. In this `Activity` the user can go to a separate `Activity` in which he can set the PIN. If no PIN is set, then a default PIN should be used.

This is the code of the first `Activity`:

```
public class activity_identification extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedPreferences pins_pref = null;
    EditText pin_entry = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_identification);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        pin_eingabe = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pin_entry);

        pins_pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("UserPin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pins_pref.edit();
        edit.putString("default_pin", "0000");
        edit.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_pin_identifikation, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_change_pin) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, pin_settings.class));
            return true;
        }

        else if (id == R.id.home) { 
            this.finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void onClickPinSummit(View button){

        if(pin_entry.getText().toString().equals( pins_pref.getString("user_pin", null).toString())) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Authorization Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Authorization Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
}
```

And this is the second `Activity`:

```
public class pin_settings extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText et_old_pin = null;
    EditText et_new_pin = null;
    EditText et_new_pin_repeat = null;
    Button btn_pin_save = null;
    TextView tv_sharedPIN = (TextView) null;

    SharedPreferences pins_prefs = null;
    private String default_pin = null;
    private String user_pin = null;
    private String old_pin = null;
    private String new_pin = null;
    private String new_pin_repeat = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pin_einstellungen);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        et_old_pin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_old_pin);
        et_new_pin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_new_pin);
        et_new_pin_repeat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_new_pin_repeat);
        btn_pin_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_pin_save);
        tv_sharedPIN = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sharedPIN);

        pins_prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("UserPin", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        general_pin = pins_prefs.getString("default_pin", null);

        tv_sharedPIN.setText(pins_prefs.getString("general_pin", null));
    }

    public void onClickNewPinSave(View button){
        old_pin = et_old_pin.getText().toString();
        new_pin = et_new_pin.getText().toString();
        new_pin_repeat = et_new_pin_repeat.getText().toString();

        if(old_pin.equals(pins_prefs.getString("default_pin",null).toString())){
            if (new_pin.equals(new_pin_repeat)){
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pins_prefs.edit();
                edit.putString("user_pin", user_pin);
                edit.commit();
                tv_sharedPIN.setText(pins_prefs.getString("user_pin", null));
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "New Pins are not the same", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Old Pin is wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that the app does not save the PIN which is set in the second `Activity`. It works as long as the app is open, but as soon as I restart it the PIN reverts back to the default PIN. I think this is because I set the default PIN in the `onCreate()` method of the first `Activity`, but I just can't figure out how to get around doing that.

Comment: What you mean by "Glabal" shared prefrences?

Comment: You can access `SharedPreferences` from anywhere where you get context.

Comment: what do you mean with context? I think I do not really understand the shared preference functional principle..

Answer (score 2):

Of course the PIN will always be reset to the default since you set it each time on startup. All you need to do to fix that is remove that line and instead use the default value which is passed into `getString()` correctly.

1. You don't need to set the default PIN at all! Remove all of that from `onCreate()`
2. `getString()` accepts a default value as second parameter. This default value is returned if **no value is set**. Let me repeat that: **The default value is return if no value has been set**.

   So instead of setting the default PIN in `onCreate()` you can simply pass in the default PIN into `getString()` and if no PIN has been set, `getString()` will then return the default PIN. So what you are looking for is this:

   ```
   String pin = preferences.getString("default_pin", "0000");
   ```

---

<sub>On a side note: Please adhere to the common Java naming conventions. Also don't hardcode so many `String`s. Use constants instead.</sub>

Comment: So where do i have to do the changes? In the first activity i have to remove the      `edit.putString("general_pin", "0000"); `    ? And in the second activity? Where do i have to initialize the Shared Preference? When I ask in the first activity for the "user_pin" the apps crashes...

Comment: @TobiF. I already told you what you need to change. Everything stays the same, but you can remove the `putString()` call which sets the default pin in `onCreate()` and then just use it like you did previously. But instead of calling `getString("default_pin", null)` use `getString("default_pin", "0000")`.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:  As  Xaver Kapeller pointed out my earlier solution wont work. Although his one is simpler, i'll fix mine just because

Set `default_pin` to `0000` if `getString(default_pin, "-1")` returns `"-1"`.

OLD: Try only setting the `default_pin` to `0000` if `default_pin` is null, which will only happen at the very first launch of your activity

Comment: You seem to be missing the point of the default value which is passed into `getString()`...